# getting a weird id in my mongodb after creating my own ObjectId

Tags: java, mongodb, scala

in my case class im creating a new mongo _id:

```
case class MongoClass(_id: ObjectId, name: String)
```

And when I create instance i go `MongoClass(new ObjectId(), "jack")`

and in mongo my document looks like:

```
{ "_id" : { "machineIdentifier" : 234234, "processIdentifier" : 3454, "counter" : 544234 }, "name" : "jack"}
```

where machineIdentifier, processIdentifier and counter came from...?

now sure whats going on here.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation:

```
ObjectId(<hexadecimal>)
Returns a new ObjectId value. The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:

a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

Comment: Link to documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Answer (score 1):

See here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Returns a new ObjectId value. The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:

a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to convert the `_id` to `hexString`?

Try this (if you haven't):

```
public String get_id() { return _id.toHexString(); }
public void set_id(ObjectId _id) { this._id = _id; }
```